# ValidationError raises when updating

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have defined a `ValidationError`. It works fine but when I try to update my form it raises. Due to this I can not update my form anymore. It is defined as following:

```
def clean_examination(self):
    new_exa = self.cleaned_data.get('examination')
    try:
        old_exa=GeneralData.objects.get(examination=self.cleaned_data.get('examination'))
    except GeneralData.DoesNotExist:
        return new_exa
    if old_exa:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Object with this examination already exists!')
    return new_exa`
```

Is it possible to "deactivate" my `ValidationError` if the form should be updated?

Additional Information:
My Model:

```
class GeneralData(models.Model):
    examination = models.ForeignKey(Examination, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text='This value is pasted in automatically and is not editable!')
    attr1= models.FloatField()
    attr2= models.FloatField()
```

My UpdateView:

```
class GeneralDataUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = GeneralData
    form_class = GeneralDataCreateForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    login_url = 'member:login'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('member:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().examination.patient_id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GeneralDataUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('member:generaldata-update',
                                     kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})
        return context
```

My Update-URL:

```
url(r'examination/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/generaldata/update/$', views.GeneralDataUpdate.as_view(), name='generaldata-update')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form is from the type `ModelForm`, you have an attribute `self.instance`. Then you can check if `self.instance.id` is set, and handle your validation.

```
if self.instance.id:
    # raise ValidationError
```

If you are not using it, should clean the id, which should be send with the request. Throw `ValidationError` if it exists, or continue..

```
id = self.cleaned_data.get('id', None)
if id:
     # raise ValidationError
```

Example:

```
def clean_examination(self):
    new_exa = self.cleaned_data.get('examination')
    try:
        old_exa = GeneralData.objects.get(
            examination=self.cleaned_data.get('examination'))
    except GeneralData.DoesNotExist:
        return new_exa

    if old_exa:
        if not self.instance.id:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Object with this examination already exists!')
    return new_exa
```

In this situation, the `ValidationError` will only be raised if there is an old `examination` if there is no old object.

Note that IF the object has an `id`, changes to the name that already exists with an OTHER `id`, you will have two different objects with the same examination. Not sure if that is okay, but that is up to you of course.